# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it (RobotFramework)

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

My test case in Robot Framework works well on my local machine.

But when I run the same test case on Oracle VM VirtualBox machine at client side after connecting it remotely(where setup for Robot Framework has been done) I get below error message while executing any sample test case.

> command: pybot.bat --argumentfile
>   c:\users\tolabr~1\appdata\local\temp\RIDEaoyfb9.d\argfile.txt
>   --listener C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotframework_ride-2.0a1-py2.7.egg\robotide\contrib\testrunner\TestRunnerAgent.py:49191:False
>   C:\Projects-GIT unable to open socket to "localhost:49191" error:
>   [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine
>   actively refused it

Even those test case which pass shows this error. 
[image]

But most of test case which works well on my local machine is not working well on client machine & I get the mentioned error message. Though I found some similar question as mine on stackoverflow, but none of them were for Robot Framework and those solution does not seems to be feasible for my case. Have anyone faced this issue on Robot Framework? Any idea on how to resolve it? Many thanks, Shoaib

Comment: Replace  'localhost' by your virtualBox IP server.

Comment: @Karthi Not able to figure how exactly I have to do the changes, any doc or link on this?